# Selecting only odd/even frames of an object

Tags: python, animation, keyframes

How can I select all odd (or even) animation keyframes for an object? Can someone please give me some working code?

Comment: i am assuming you want some python code? so i added "python"as tag here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following script to select even or odd keyframes using `select_keyframes(EVEN)` or `select_keyframes(ODD)`, respectively. Make sure you have an active `DOPESHEET_EDITOR` or `TIMELINE` area open and make sure you have selected an object with keyframes.

```
import bpy

EVEN = 0
ODD = 1

obj = bpy.context.object

def deselect_keyframes():
    area_type = 'DOPESHEET_EDITOR'
    areas  = [area for area in bpy.context.window.screen.areas if area.type == area_type]

    with bpy.context.temp_override(area=areas[0]):
        bpy.ops.action.select_all(action='DESELECT')

def select_keyframes(odd_or_even):
    if obj.animation_data is None:
        print("The active object has no animation data and thus no keyframes")
        return
    for fcurve in obj.animation_data.action.fcurves:
        for keyframe in fcurve.keyframe_points:
            keyframe.select_control_point = int(keyframe.co[0]) % 2 == odd_or_even

deselect_keyframes()
select_keyframes(ODD) # or use EVEN
```

Comment: fyi, deselecting or having an opened timeline area is useless here.

Comment: @lemon im not sure what you mean by useless? if you don't have an area of type dopesheet or timeline open you will get an error.

Comment: but you don't need to deselect anything, so 'deselect_keyframes' is not usefull.

Comment: i've tested that for example if you have 10 keyframes and keyframe 5 selected, and then execute the script to select even frames you get all even frames selected including frame 5 which will not get deselected for some reason. that is why i had to deselect everything first.

Comment: ok, my bad (just tested it). Forgive it!

Comment: haha no worries, its just weird that it doesnt deselect frames that were manually selected so i was forced to use the bpy.ops which i tried to avoid xd

Comment: this is due to the handles... you have to set select_control_point, select_left_handle, select_right_handle...